# Getting javascript to open links in new window

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I'm helping a friend try to get links to open to a new window in Javascript within the code I was given for a banner image carousel.

I've tried various tweaks with my limited knowledge, but none seem to do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var i = 0; 
var image = new Array();   
// LIST OF IMAGES 
image[0] = "banner01.jpg"; 
image[1] = "banner02.jpg"; 
image[2] = "banner03.jpg";   
image[3] = "banner04.jpg";   
var k = image.length-1;    

var caption = new Array(); 
// LIST OF CAPTIONS 
caption[0] = "caption01"; 
caption[1] = "caption02"; 
caption[2] = "caption03"; 
caption[3] = "caption04"; 

var link= new Array();   
// LIST OF LINKS 
link[0] = "url01"; 
link[1] = "url02"; 
link[2] = "url03";   
link[3] = "url04";   

function swapImage(){ 
    var el = document.getElementById("mydiv"); 
    el.innerHTML=caption[i]; 
    var img = document.getElementById("slide"); 
    img.src= image[i]; 
    var a = document.getElementById("link"); 
    a.href= link[i];
    window.open("_blank"); 

    if(i < k ) { i++;}  
    else  { i = 0; } 
    setTimeout("swapImage()",5000); 
} 

function addLoadEvent(func) { 
    var oldonload = window.onload; 
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') { 
        window.onload = func; 
    } else  { 
        window.onload = function() { 
            if (oldonload) { 
                oldonload(); 
            } 
            func(); 
        } 
    } 
}

addLoadEvent(function() { 
    swapImage(); 
});
</script>
```

We'd like the result to be that clicking on the image which appears will open the corresponding hyperlink in a new window. Thanks in advance for any assistance to point us in the right direction!

Comment: I see your using `a` tags for your links. Try adding the `target="_blank"` attribute to them!

Comment: Do you mean in the listing of the links...that I should modify them so that, for example, the first one would read:

link[0] = "http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank";         ?

If so, that doesn't work; it kills the whole script and none of the images rotate through. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: No do it like this: `<a href="javascript:myfunction();" target="_blank">Link</a>`

Comment: Either I'm not understanding where you think these should be inserted, or they don't work. There is no textual link in this; the user clicks on the image rotating through the carousel of images.

Comment: This thing in your code: `a.href= link[i];` prooves me that you have, indeed, textual links in your project.